# item.setData with a QStandardItemModel triggers a segfault

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QStandardItemModel` for which I would like to store for each item another `QStandardItemModel` as `UserData`. Here is a snippet which reproduces the unexpected behavior:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    groups_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()   
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem('test')        
    item.setData(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(),257)        
    groups_model.appendRow(item)        
    groups_model.data(groups_model.index(0,0),257)
```

This triggers a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong to trigger such behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since the "QStandardItemModel" object is not assigned to a variable then it is instantly removed (this is a very common behavior in PyQt/PySide2). The solution is to assign it to a variable or extend its scope by passing it a parent:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

CustomRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    groups_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem("test")
    another_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    item.setData(another_model, CustomRole)
    groups_model.appendRow(item)
    groups_model.data(groups_model.index(0, 0), CustomRole)
```

Or

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

CustomRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    groups_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem("test")
    item.setData(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(groups_model), CustomRole)
    groups_model.appendRow(item)
    groups_model.data(groups_model.index(0, 0), CustomRole)
```